# WPf Datepicker Input modification

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, datepicker

I am creating a form using wpf/c#. I am looking to programatically change/interpret the user's typed input in the `wpf toolkit DatePicker`.

For example, the user types "Today", and when the control looses focus the date is interpreted and set to the current date using my c# function.

Should I listen to the lostFocus event or is there a better way of changing how a typed input date is parsed?

I do not care to change the display format of the date picker. I am developing this application using the mvvm pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so finally I looked into the sourcecode of `DatePicker` and theres not much I can do in terms of converters etc as most stuff is private and the only two available formats are "short" and "long". Finally, I will have to create my own control, probably in part using the solution above by Aviad. However, here's a quick temporary solution until then (where `DateHelper` is my custom parser class):

```
   public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
    {
        protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                this.TryTransformDate();
            }

            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.TryTransformDate();
            base.OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(e);
        }

        protected void TryTransformDate()
        {
            DateTime tryDate;
            if (DateHelper.TryParseDate(this.Text, out tryDate))
            {
                switch (this.SelectedDateFormat)
                {
                    case DatePickerFormat.Short: 
                        {
                            this.Text = tryDate.ToShortDateString();
                            break;
                        }

                    case DatePickerFormat.Long: 
                        {
                            this.Text = tryDate.ToLongDateString();
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Typical scenario for a value converter. Define a value converter that accepts a `string` and converts it to a `DateTime`. In your binding, define the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to be `LostFocus` thus:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DateText, 
                Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

Comment: This seems to be a good solution in theory, however for the datepicker, the wpf beats me to the conversion and an exception is thrown on LostFocus '"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."'. How can I do the conversion "before" the wpf framework tries to do it for me? I'm tempted to use the lostFocus event solution.. winforms-style :(

Comment: Wait, are you using a `TextBox` or a `DatePicker` from the WPF toolkit?