# Validate invalid input on DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetimepicker, xceed

I have a DateTimePicker as follows:

```
<UserControl
...
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
...
>
     <xctk:DateTimePicker Name="MyDatePicker" 
           Value="{Binding MyDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
           Format="Custom" FormatString="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"                
           AutoCloseCalendar="True"/>
```

I'm using `IDateErrorInfo` on my data model to handle business logic errors; for example:

```
public class MyViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {                
            string error = DataValid();
            CanExecute = (error == string.Empty);

            return error;
        }
    }
```

`CanExecute` is a property which manages whether the user can select to submit the data.  This all works well, however, if I simply select the date and mash the keyboard (type random letters), the date is reset to `01/01/01`.  What I would like to happen is for the date to effectively remain unchanged (that is, as it was before I mashed the keyboard).  However, I can't seem to find a place to handle the casting error which obviously is occurring when this happens.

How can I trap this?

(The DateTimePicker control is part of the [WPF Extension Kit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Documentation))

Comment: What do you mean by 'Mashed the keyboard' ?

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean typing random characters; the control is from here: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the way the control handles errors you can handle errors yourself in a subclass, an example of this in my old question [Wpf Datepicker Input modification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2020063/61991)